# JMeter response times is high compared to calling the API directly

Tags: jmeter

We have a REST API. When we call the API through the jmeter we get high response times compared to calling the API directly with a c# client that makes a Http request.

There are no resources or anything. It is a POST call that returns around 1 MB of data. With jmeter the latency is around 300 ms vs calling the API directly the latency is 100 ms.

Why is this difference ? What settings should we tweak in jmeter ? Tried tweaking the SSL settings. But that did not make any difference.

Any suggestions ?

THanks

Answer (score 1):

We cannot say anything meaningful without seeing the C# code and your JMeter configuration.

Given you're sending the same requests you should be getting the same responses in more or less the same time so use an external sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the requests from C# http request and JMeter and compare them. Amend JMeter's HTTP Request sampler configuration to 100% match the C# http request including [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

Also if your C# http request supports proxy (it [should theoretically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy?view=net-6.0)) you can just record the request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), this way you will get the same configuration of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager).

With regards to "tweaking" JMeter I can only think of [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html).